# How to run the same playbooks and inventories with or without a jumphost?

Tags: ssh, ansible

I have few playbooks and inventories and I need to run them from 2 different locations.

One that requires a jumphost and one that doesn't.

I have defined the jumphost in my inventory but when trying to run the playbook on the local one (no jumphost required) will fail.

Is there a way to load the SSH related vars based on ansible hostname?

Answer (score -1):

If you just need to run things on the local host.. you can do that with specific tasks:

try local_action.. e.g.:

```
- name: copy file
  local_action:
    module: copy
    src: stfile
    dest: /path/to/testfile
```

or you can use delegate_to:

```
- name: copy a file
  delegate_to: localhost
  copy:
    src: testfile
    dest: /path/to/testfile
```

Edit: OK it seems I misread your question. Your question seems to be that you are running playbooks off two different hosts, one works and one fails, and so you need some logic that will select different variables for you based on the host?

You can include logic in the tasks using the when conditional like so :

```
     - name: get ansible hostname    
       local_action:
          module: shell
          cmd: hostname
        register: hostname_output

     - shell: echo '{{variablefornonjumpbox}}' 
       when: hostname_output.stdout.find('jumpbox') != -1"
```

If you need to change the SSH target and details based on the hostname, you can use special variables like the ones at the bottom of this page:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html

Hopefully that helps.. If not I will need some clarification on the variables you are using and the errors you see.

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question ?

Comment: Hmm I expanded on my answer a bit.. Hopefully that helps but without more details unfortunately I can't give the exact solution